# Extracting the Original WhatsApp Message from Button Payload in Python

Tags: python-3.x, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have created a custom WhatsApp template with buttons, and when a user clicks on a button, I receive a payload via a webhook. The payload contains information about the button clicked, but I also need to extract the message that was replied to when the button was pressed.

Here's a snippet of the WhatsApp object I receive when the webhook is triggered:

```
whatsapp_object = {
'object': 'whatsapp_business_account',
'entry': [{
    'id': '*******',
    'changes': [{
        'value': {
            'messaging_product': '********',
            'metadata': {
                'display_phone_number': '*******',
                'phone_number_id': '******'
            },
            'contacts': [{
                'profile': {'name': 'Akasha'},
                'wa_id': '*********'
            }],
            'messages': [{
                'context': {
                    'from': '********',
                    'id': 'wamid.*******'
                },
                'from': '*****',
                'id': 'wamid.*****',
                'timestamp': '1706271884',
                'type': 'button',
                'button': {
                    'payload': 'Approve',
                    'text': 'Approve'
                }
            }]
        },
        'field': 'messages'
    }]
}]
```

}

When a button is clicked, I receive the payload, but I also need to extract the message that the user was replying to. How can I achieve this in Python?

I appreciate any insights you can provide or if you could direct me to the right direction. Thank you!